# Adding layout constraints to a button

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, cgpoint

Refreshing my self with Swift ... I want to center this button `loginButton.center = self.view.center` at the bottom of the view. The current code centers the button perfectly horizontally and vertically..

I have tried messing around with CGPoints and subView's but have had no luck.

Comment: can you post all the related code?

Comment: @Honey the only piece of code missing was this and thats it

`let loginButton:PPLoginButton = PPLoginButton.init()`

Comment: @JoshuaPaulsen it's nice to say that the question title needs constraints instead of frame layout

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you **are not** using Auto Layout. So this is what you are looking for:

```
button.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2,
                        y: view.bounds.height - button.bounds.height / 2)
```

If you **want to** use Auto Layout instead go with **Sh_Khan**'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let pos = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.maxY - 80)
       loginButton.center = pos

       loginButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

       self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
```

Comment: You are mixing auto layout (`loginButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`) with setting frames manually (`loginButton.center = pos`) in this answer.

Comment: @AndréSlotta Thanks!